# React Native function not recognised on TouchableOpacity function "onPress"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I dont understand why the first example of code renders ok onPress of the button and the other example when I put it inside a fundtion it does not recognise the function.

```
//This executes as expected

 render() {
   return (

     <View style={styles.container}>

       <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this)}>

          <Text style={{paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10, color: 
         '#FF0000'}}>Prova</Text>

       </TouchableOpacity>

     </View>

-------------------------------------------------------------------
//Here it can't recognise the function

func1(){
 this.handlePress.bind(this);
 };


 render() {
   return (

     <View style={styles.container}>

       <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.func1()}>

          <Text style={{paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 10, color: 
         '#FF0000'}}>Prova</Text>

       </TouchableOpacity>

     </View>
```

Comment: Maybe you want something like this :
`<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.handlePress()}>`. Where is you `handlePress` function defined ?

Answer (score 2):

Convert your function to an arrow function, and forget about binding...
Arrow function is automatically bound to its parent...

```
handlePress = () => {};
```

-

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePress}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to bind this.handlePress.bind(this); inside func1.

Just call it

```
func1(){
    this.handlePress()
}
```

With this.handlePress.bind(this), you are not invoking the function, but just returning a function bounfd to 'this'